# Copy Insight through API

Tags: gooddata

Is it possible to copy an insight through the API?  I know it's possible to "save as new" an insight through the designer, but I would like to do so programmatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

any insight is metadata object, so basically it should be enough to post the same body to metadata resource: address is `/gdc/md/<project ID>/obj?createAndGet=true` and body the same like the original one (you fetch it with GET to `/gdc/md/<project ID>/obj/<your object ID>` as visible in address bar.

Those help pages might help (the principle is the same inside the project):
[Migrate objects between projects](https://help.gooddata.com/display/doc/Migrating+Selected+Objects+between+Projects)